# How do I dynamically grab data row-by-row and calculate a distinct count where parameters are met?

Tags: powerbi, dax

**INTRO**

I realize the title makes the problem sound simple, however, this task has proved incredibly difficult for me and it's taken up hours of my time every day for the past week. With that being said, any help is appreciated!

The first table involved is LoadView, which contains the fields LoadNumber, CarrierID, and BookedFrom. The second table is LoadBaseView, which contains the fields LoadNumber, CarrierID, and BookedOnDateTime. These two are related by LoadNumber.

The visualization I wanna add to is the following, where the new row would be "New Carriers" listed right under "Carriers": [image: Matrix to add to]

Lastly, preliminary info wise, that table is just a matrix with LoadView[BookedFrom] as the only context (Autobook, etc.) and simple measures across LoadView along with it.

**PROBLEM**

Now that I've (hopefully) laid everything out clearly, let me explain exactly what I am looking for. I would like to count the amount of new carriers that have booked in each BookedFrom category, i.e. I would like to count the amount of carriers booking that have never booked before for each category. This means that any carrier could potentially be counted in each BookedFrom column, just to clarify. I've tried many different measure to capture this and I've run into a whole host of problems, including memory insufficiencies to exceeding available resources. The latter's DAX is the following:

```
IsFirstCarrierBookedFrom* = 

Var current_booked_from = MIN(dsgLoadView[BookedFrom])

Var T1 = ADDCOLUMNS(ALL(dsgLoadView),"BookedOnDateTime",RELATED(dsgLoadBaseView[BookedOnDateTime]))

Var T2 = GROUPBY(T1,dsgLoadView[CarrierId],dsgLoadView[BookedOn],"MinBookedOnDateTime",MINX(CURRENTGROUP(),[BookedOnDateTime]))

Var T3 = NATURALINNERJOIN(T1,T2)

Var T4 = FILTER(T3,[BookedOnDateTime]=[MinBookedOnDateTime])

RETURN
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT([CarrierId]),FILTER(T4,[BookedFrom]=current_booked_from),USERELATIONSHIP(dsgLoadView[BookedOnDate],dsgCalendar[Date]))
```

The above results in this error: [image: Error message]

This next attempt results in a memory insufficiency error:

```
TotalFirstCarrierBooks* = 

Var current_row_carrier_id = MIN(dsgLoadBaseView[CarrierId])

Var current_row_booked_from = MIN(dsgLoadView[BookedFrom])

Var first_booked_from_date_time = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN(dsgLoadBaseView[BookedOnDateTime]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(dsgLoadBaseView),
        dsgLoadBaseView[CarrierId]=current_row_carrier_id
    ),
    FILTER(
        All(dsgLoadView),
        dsgLoadView[BookedFrom]=current_row_booked_from
    )
)

Var is_first_date = IF(first_booked_from_date_time=MIN(dsgLoadBaseView[BookedOnDateTime]),1,0)

RETURN
SUMX(dsgLoadBaseView,is_first_date)
```

With that being said, if I take out the BookedFrom bits (current_row_booked_from, etc.) the measure works and when alongside LoadNumber it returns a 1 or 0, denoting that the LoadNumber was or was not the first booking by the Carrier. I decided this wasn't the right path, though, due to that memory error. Also, summing up these 1's gets me duplicate bookings per Carrier per BookedFrom. In other words, a Carrier can book 2 loads via Manual at the same DateTime and, as those 2 rows would have 1's per the logic, that would add up to 2 which is a no-no.

**THANK YOU**

Seriously, to anyone who got this far! This problem has eaten up a ton of time for me, I've Googled relentlessly and I've watched countless YouTube videos. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I unable to provide a solution that would work because I don't have the data and its impossible to solve questions like these without the actual data, but I do know DAX so based on my experience here are my suggestions.

For measure IsFirstCarrierBookedFrom:

1. Substitute DISTINCTCOUNT with SUMX ( VALUES ( Table[CarriedID] ), 1 ) and see if that resulst in better performance
2. You are adding a column to dsgLoadView with RELATED, what is the cardinality of this table? Pay attention to these details and based on that supply a smaller table to ADDCOLUMNS and then use CALCULATE to compute BookedOnDateTime
3. Functions like NATURALINNERJOIN utilize the slower engine of DAX
4. You are probably applying a huge table T4 into the filter context with CALCULATE

For measure TotalFirstCarrierBooks:

1. You are probably iterating a huge tabls inside CALCULATE in the variable first_booked_from_date_time, try to change that to this:

```
VAR first_booked_from_date_time =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( dsgLoadBaseView[BookedOnDateTime] ),
        dsgLoadBaseView[CarrierId] = current_row_carrier_id,
        dsgLoadView[BookedFrom] = current_row_booked_from,
        REMOVEFILTERS ( dsgLoadBaseView ),
        REMOVEFILTERS ( dsgLoadView )
    )
```

2. The RETURN part isn't working how you would expect it to, variables in DAX are constants, before RETURN the value of is_first_date is computed and is now a fixed value, nothing can change it, let's assume it is 10 then inside SUMX ( dsgLoadBaseView, is_first_date ) you are summing 10 for each row of the table dsgLoadBaseView